# Accessing Bloomberg API from client's browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, bloomberg

**Is it possible to access blpapi from javascript running in the client's browser?**

I wish to access bloomberg's API from javascript running in the client's browser, in the assumption that the client has an open bloomberg session and therefore bbcomm is running.

Conceptually, this would be the same as accessing the blpapi on the client side from python.

However, all existing solutions I found in js appear to be server-side:

**[blpapi-node](https://github.com/bloomberg/blpapi-node/tree/master/examples)** (node-based)

**[blpapi-httm](https://github.com/bloomberg/blpapi-http)** (creates a server where to post http request)

**[blpapi-react](https://github.com/teresaibarra/blpapi-react)** (cannot make this module work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can access Bloomberg data natively in JavaScript via Web AppPortal. This allows you to write web based applications that run inside LP Components.

To learn more about Web AppPortal, go to MYAP 5

To download the SDK, please type SDK -> select SDK -> AppPortal Web SDK -> click Install.

Comment: I just took a look at the docs, it looks like the app needs to be running in the terminal context for the API to be available, so you can't access from say, chrome.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's correct. You cannot open the page in a standalone browser. The app must run inside a Launchpad Component, which hosts the Chromium web browser.

Alternatively, you can consume the COM Data Control in JavaScript. Or build a plug-in using any of the supported languages (C++, C#, VB.NET, Java) run it inside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is obsolete, see Mourad Barakat's answer above

Conversation with Bloomberg Support confirms this is not possible**

BB say they don't support javascript access, and that one solution is to use their Server API to use the authentication of the client (who has a bb terminal open) to query data and return it to the client

**An alternative hack**

An alternative hack is to create an executable mini-server that the client downloads and launches, and that offers an http interface to get data to the webapp.

For example, this could be done in Flask in Python, and in fact it has already been done by **[blpapi-web](https://github.com/pricingmonkey/blpapi-web)** (excluding the executable part, for which you can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/#Features) and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) for Windows and [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Mac)

Comment: It's possible now to access Bloomberg data in JavaScript. Please see my post above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I was waiting to accept my own answer in in hopes that something like this could show up. I'm reading the info now, very useful thanks